# Having issue while login in php ,ajax and API

Tags: php, ajax, api

Here i am posting username and password and it should verify it. if success it will return the username else it will give error. so now i am confused how to proceed as i **am new to ajax**. Please help me to get solution guys.

**NOTE:**
I tried to get my response from **POSTMAN** it gives me a response if username and password is **correct** like this

```
{
    "username": "Felix_Col"
}
```

if username and password is **wrong** it gives error like this

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "",
        "code": "401",
        "date": "Fri May 10 16:53:17 IST 2019"
    }
}
```

But i am **stuck** when i am using **HTML front-end** in the browser.Please help me to get solution i am stuck till now

```
    <body>
        <!-- Begin Page Content -->
        <div id="container">
           <form id="loginform" method="post">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
                <div id="lower">
                    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Save Login Credentials</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
                </div><!--/ lower-->
            </form>
        </div><!--/ container-->
        <!-- End Page Content -->
        <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(res)
       {

            window.location = '/user-page.php';

       }
   });
 });
});
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: A more common method for deleting a record is to have a status field on the record itself.  So rather than moving the record, you flag it as deleted.  The down side of this means that any query accessing this table has to be modified to take this new field into account.

Comment: Anyone is there please help me out

Answer (score 1):

make a replica of players  table as players_backup and insert the data first to backup table and once you get the num rows after inserting is greater than zero that means the data has been inserted. after this you can delete the data from the players tables. Simple.

i am assuming that players and players_bkp have same schemas.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    // get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql  = "insert into players_bkp select * FROM players WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $rc = $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
    $rc = $stmt->execute();
    $tid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
    if($tid  > 0){  //that means record is inserted and you can actually delete the record from your players table
        // delete record from database
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM players WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
        }
        $mysqli->close();

        // redirect user after delete is successful
        header("Location: view.php");
    }
}
else
// if the 'id' variable isn't set, redirect the user
{
    header("Location: view.php");
}
```

Comment: This answer creates data inconsistency. read question carefully "I want to have a back-up of the deleted record on another table" in your answer you insert record before deleting it. what if delete query fails?

Comment: Please help me out in calling the user login api. please